# Django Rest Framework: why is my api call much slower in production than dev?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've a django app that's deployed on an ec2 instance with docker and nginx. An api call that takes 700ms on my local system takes 15s on the production server. Even with debug set to false, on my local machine the call returns within 600-800ms but on production it consistently takes 15-20s to return.
What causes this difference in performance? How does the way django handles api calls in debug differ from prod? I already use select_related and prefetch wherever possible. What changes could I make to speed up the api calls on the prod env?

Edit: Both the servers use postgres DBs with the same data and the api calls transfer 50kbs of data.

Edit: Turns out one of the serializers is where the bulk of the time is being spent i.e 14-19s and the rest of the api code combined takes 1-2s. The serializer apparently takes too long inside the `to_representation` method. Here's the serializer definition:

```
class DataSourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    instance = InstanceSerializer()
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = DataSource
        exclude = ('previous', 'version', )

        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {
                'write_only': True,
                'required': False
                },
            'db_staging': {
                'required': False
                }
        }

    def validate(self, data):
        password = data.get('password')

        if password in ['', None] and self.instance.password in ['', None]:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": "This field is required"})

        return data

    # TODO: Merge in ROAD-1234
    def create(self, validated_data):
        session = self.context.get('request', None)
        if session is not None:
            session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session.session.session_key)
        instance_data = validated_data.pop('instance', None)

        # test config values
        try:
            test_connection(validated_data)
        except (exc.OperationalError, err.OperationalError):
            error = {'message': "Invalid credentials. Unable to connect to the data source."}
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error)
        except exc.TimeoutError:
            error = {'message': "Connection timed out. Unable to connect to the data source."}
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error)

        instance, _ = InstanceMetadata.objects.get_or_create(session=session, **instance_data)
        obj, _ = DataSource.objects.get_or_create(instance=instance, version=instance, **validated_data)
        return obj
```

This is the model definiton:

```
class DataSource(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    instance = models.ForeignKey(InstanceMetadata, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='instance')
    db_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    host = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    port = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    db_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    db_staging = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None, null=True)
    version = models.ForeignKey(InstanceMetadata, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    previous = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, default=None, to_field='id')

    objects = managers.DataSourceManager()

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.db_name, ) + self.instance.natural_key()
    natural_key.dependences = ['spinner.InstanceMetadata']

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['version', 'instance', 'db_name'],
                                    name='unique source')
        ]

    def get_unique_attr(self):
        return {
            'db_name': self.db_name,
            'instance__name': self.instance.name}
```

Is there something that explains this hold up in the serialization?

Comment: What is the instance class for ec2? maybe it's just an underpowered instance. It could also be a difference in ammount of data in the DB

Comment: `What causes this difference in performance?` there are many layers involved so this is completely unanswerable without _debugging details_. Is it django part or webserver? Is it python code or database query? Which exactly peace of code? With these details also please specify: django version, DBMS with version.

Comment: I've narrowed down the scope.